# Слово "эпитет" не в лингвистическом значении

Tags: многозначность

**[Эпитет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82)**

> Логика различает суждения синтетические — такие, в которых сказуемое
>   называет признак, не заключённый в подлежащем (эта гора высока) и
>   ***аналитические — такие, в которых сказуемое лишь выявляет признак, уже имеющийся в подлежащем (люди смертны)***.
>
> Эпитет — начало разложения слитного комплекса представлений — выделяет
>   признак, уже данный в определяемом слове, поскольку это необходимо для
>   сознания, разбирающегося в явлениях; признак, выделяемый им, может
>   казаться несущественным, случайным, но не таков он для творческой
>   мысли автора.
>
> ---

Теперь мой текст  (на п/ж и курсивные вопросы в скобках не надо обращать внимания; только на контекст, связанный с "этитетом"!):

> Рим не знал своих богов в лицо. Не поэтизировал их, не придумывал им
>   биографий. «Гений – хранитель отдельного действия, жил не дольше, чем
>   действие.
>
> Гений – хранитель человека – не дольше, чем сам человек: он жил и
>   умирал вместе с самим человеком, и эти божественные существа можно
>   считать бессмертными лишь в том смысле, что постоянно вновь
>   зарождаются подобные действия и **однородные** *(?!)* люди, а вместе
>   с ними и одинаковые гении», – пишет Теодор Моммзен. Римлянин
>   обожествлял явления мира, всякое человеческое проявление и даже
>   **буквально** – **букву** *(?!)* закона. Самое ничтожное событие жизни вызывало возникновение одновременно нескольких божеств. Так,
>   существовали две богини для первого шага из дома и две богини для
>   первого шага по направлению домой.
>
> Бог честного слова. Бог случайности. Бог крика младенца. Бог
>   промелькнувшей мысли. Бог для всякого начинания. Бог существовал именно для этого мгновения,
>   и никаких других функций для него не находилось. Списки богов были
>   бесконечны, имена их звучали **эпитетами** *(только не эпитет!)*.
>
> Нередко имена отделялись от эпитетов, забывались, и тогда эпитеты
>   превращались уже в самостоятельных богов. Любого из них можно было
>   выбрать для особого почитания или лишь иногда поминать, а можно просто
>   — забыть. Существовали и враждебные человеку 
>   силы: бог зловредного воздуха, лихорадки, воровства. В общество богов
>   вводили и весьма отвлеченные понятия, которым даже строили храмы, —
>   например, «Милосердию века» или «Страху и бледности».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что логический эпитет, что поэтический - всё равно это определение,признак предмета, выраженный прилагательным : «в отличие от обычного логического определения, которое выделяет данный предмет из многих, эпитет либо выделяет в предмете одно из его свойств, либо – как метафорический эпитет – переносит на него свойства другого предмета» [Литературный энциклопедический словарь 1987: 512]. Имена богов часто не прилагательные, они описывают род их занятий - чем они ведают, поэтому можно сказать, что они построены не по принципу эпитета, а по принципу **перифразы.**: peri — «вокруг»,  phraso — «говорю». 
*Юпитер - владыка людей и богов, верховный бог.*

Перифраза — это семантически неделимое, иносказательное выражение, которое описывает содержание другого слова или сочетания слов. Этот троп в образной форме характеризует определенное явление, событие, указывая на их специфичные, отличительные черты, которые легко позволяют узнать объект описания. Писатель пользуется перифразой, заменяя название предмета или явления описанием существенных, определяющих его черт и признаков, создающих в нашем представлении яркую жизненную картину. Перифраза называет понятие или явление другими словами, сохраняя при этом его смысл, например: голубая планета (Земля); чёрное золото (нефть); второй хлеб (картофель); король грибов (белый гриб); корабль пустыни (верблюд); стальное полотно (железная дорога); канцелярская крыса (чиновник); вечный город (Рим); вечер жизни (старость); хозяин тайги (медведь); наши младшие братья (животные).

В своем творчестве А.С. Пушкин активно прибегал к использованию перифразы: У. Шекспир — творец Макбета; поэт Адам Мицкевич — певец Литвы; певец Гяура и Жуана — Байрон. Подробнее: http://russkiiyazyk.ru/leksika/chto-takoe-perifraza.html